# Submitting Changes pure SqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlconnection, dataprovider

I need to get 2-way binding DB to DataGrid, so I'm using this method:

```
    private void SetTable(string tableName)
    {
        var dataGridView1 = new DataGridView { DataSource = GetData(tableName), Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        groupBox1.Text = tableName;
        groupBox1.Controls.Clear();
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
    }

    private static DataTable GetData(string tableName)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName), connection);

            connection.Open();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            var result = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetTable(comboBox1.Text);
    }
```

so I have one-way binding. So I'd like to do some changes and after send them back to db. So question is simple: should I do it manually or analogue of L2S `SubmitChanges()` exists? I should use SQL requests only. No EF, No L2S and so on.

So I'd like to get some modified/added/removed rows from `DataGrid` and update them in database. 
I can do it manually, using 2 lists and after make an except query, but I'd like to get it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine what has changed by calling [GetChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649.aspx) and/or [update directly by using a TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx).